# RandomRange Function 'Undeclared Identifier' Error?

Tags: delphi

I am trying to use the randomrange function in Delphi XE2 but for some reason it keeps giving me an undeclared identifier error when trying to run it, here is my code.

```
var
  Form3: TForm3;
  number_of_digits, values, single, doubledig, triple, four, I : nativeint;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

begin
  Randomize;
  number_of_digits := radiogroup1.ItemIndex;
  single := RandomRange(0, 9);
  doubledig := RandomRange(10,99);
  triple := RandomRange(100,999);
  four := RandomRange(1000,9999);
  case number_of_digits of
  0 : values := single;
  1 : values := doubledig;
  2 : values := triple;
  3 : values := four;
  end;
```

The error I am getting is

> E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'RandomRange'

Any help would be appreciated.. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`RandomRange`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Math.RandomRange) function is in the `Math` unit. Add that unit to your `uses` clause.

```
uses
  System.Math;
```